# LibreOffice: stop automatic formatting of text into a formula?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

In LibreOffice, I'm entering some text into cells, which happens to look like a math problem:

```
-5 / -10 / -15
```

The program assumes I want to calculate this, and sticks an equals sign automatically in the front of the cell contents for me:

```
=-5 / -10 / -15
```

I've looked all over the options and autocorrect-options pages, but I cannot seem to find a way to disable this behaviour.
Short of sticking it in quotes, like `"-5 / -10 / -15"`, is there a way to stop the program from automatically adding the equals sign?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this by right-clicking the cell and setting the format as "Text" before entering anything. That has kept the text exactly as I entered it.

[image: LibreOffice Calc Text format]

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend your text with an apostrophe ' like this:

```
'-5 / -10 / -15
```

Libreoffice will drop that first character, and consider everything after that as just string of text.

Comment: This is great if you're just working with numbers, try inputting `'-x +6` and you'll notice that the apostrophe remains, unlike when handling numbers. FYI, my Calc replaces the expression `-x +6` as `=-'x'+6` for some stupid reason